# Html table Collapse in TD Level when i change alignment changes it should be fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code when i click Order column (or) second column `Order` header changes its alignment it is not fixed it comes down.

Here I have the sample code that not properly done.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
    <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
    <a href="#demo" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse">Simple collapsible</a>
    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion">
        <td>Some Stuff</td>
        <td>Some more stuff</td>
        <td>And some more</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div id="accordion" class="collapse">Hidden by default</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table fixed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Order Number</th>
        <th>Order Date</th>
        <th>Total Price</th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".order1">
        <td>&gt;</td>
        <td>1001</td>
        <td data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".order1">9/29/2016</td>
        <td>$126.27</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="collapse order1">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Shirt</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>CHECK</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because you've tried to play the system by adding irrelevant wordings.

Comment: i don't know why you are saying like this.

Comment: That's not really playing the system, as SO doesn't have any kind of algorithm to make keyword stuffing worthwhile. I will however vote to close the question as it's too broad and shows no research effort.

Comment: did you checked my edit? @Praveen then you know what I mean

Comment: Okay leave it somewhere i made mistake can any one give me an example of collapse in TD level . When i click a td data sub data should be loaded down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The headers' alignement where changing because when then second row appears the 'C' column width increase so obviously the others decrease so that the table total width does not change.
So the simplest solution I think is to fix the column size like that :

```css
td{ width : 80px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
    <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
    <a href="#demo" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse">Simple collapsible</a>
    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion">
        <td>Some Stuff</td>
        <td>Some more stuff</td>
        <td>And some more</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div id="accordion" class="collapse">Hidden by default</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table fixed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Order Number</th>
        <th>Order Date</th>
        <th>Total Price</th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".order1">
        <td>&gt;</td>
        <td>1001</td>
        <td data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".order1">9/29/2016</td>
        <td>$126.27</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="collapse order1">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Shirt</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>CHECK</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I Need td cloapse in ajax,When i click a TD value its value should shown below. I need to view the data when i click a td value not the entire TR.

Comment: Well, in that case yopu have to rethink, your entire design. If you keep that design you will have to show the entire tr and hide all the td but the one you want to keep. I don't think this is the best to do it.